# How to control y-axis in a DoubleYscale plot with LatticeExtra

Tags: r, lattice

Unfortunately I could not find an answer in the archive, even if similiar questions were already asked.

I would like to plot a graph with two y-axis, which works fine using LatticeExtra
doubleYScale(obj1, obj2 , add.ylab2 = F, use.style = F). However, I am not able to control the graphical parameters of the y-axis, especially tick marks.
The scales argument which I use in the first object only affects the x-axis for whatever reason.

Is there an easy solution for this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your problem; perhaps it was fixed in a patch? I have no issue adjusting the `scales` options for the two axes.

```
foo <- list(x = 1:100, y = cumsum(rnorm(100)))

obj1 <- xyplot(y ~ x, foo, type = "l", scales = list(y = list(tck = 1)))
obj2 <- xyplot(y ^ 2 ~ x, foo, type = "l",
               scales = list(y = list(tck = 3, rot = 90)))

doubleYScale(obj1, obj2, add.axis = TRUE)
```

[image: Imgur]